# Rails overwrite CSV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, controller, export

I'm currently using this code:

```
CSV.open "application.csv", "a+" do |csv|

  csv << [ "#{params[:first_name]}", "#{params[:last_name]}","#{params[:company]}","#{params[:email]}", "#{params[:phone]}", "#{params[:business]}", "#{params[:services]}", "#{params[:employees]}", "#{params[:turnover]}"  ]

end
```

Which writes an extra row to the csv each time, what can I put instead of `"a+"` that will overwrite the entire file each time, so it always only has one row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `'w'` mode. BTW, why do you write `"#{params[:first_name]}"` where `params[:first_name]` would be enough? The code should look:

```
CSV.open 'application.csv', 'w' do |csv|
  csv << [params[:first_name], params[:last_name], params[:company], params[:email], params[:phone], params[:business], params[:services], params[:employees], params[:turnover], params[:c4l_services]]
end
```